# Powershell:Replacing Unique Values in a text document using Find and Replace

Tags: powershell

I'm decently new to powershell but trying to pick up more to expedite things.

I have a text document that specifies SQL connection strings (not crucial to this question). The two values I'm looking for are SQL Server Name and a database name. The SQL Server Name will be different on each machine because it's a local instance but the database name will stay the same.

Essentially, here is the string:

localSQLConString=Database=Internal_TrainingProject;Server=MBDatabase\SQLEXPRESS14;Integrated Security=True;

i thought about pulling these into Powershell as variables (using user prompts) like so:

```
param (
    [string]$SQL = $( Read-Host "Input SQL Server Instance Name." )
    [string]$DB = $( Read-Host "Input SQL Database Name." )
)
(Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test.txt")
```

However, I'm having trouble with the find and replace piece. Each text file will have commonalities like localSQLConString=, Database= and Server=.

I was hoping to do something like

localSQLConString=Database=**$DB**;Server=**$SQL**;Integrated Security=True;

but I'm having trouble splitting up the common text between the variables.

Any assistance any of you have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$connectionstring="Database=Internal_TrainingProject;Server=MBDatabase\SQLEXPRESS14;Integrated Security=True;"

#split connectionstring to hash table
$Hash=@{}
$connectionstring -split ";" | where {$_ -ne ""} | %{$Hash[$_.Split('=')[0]]=$_.Split('=')[1]}

#modification elements
$Hash['Server']=$SQL 
$Hash['Database']=$DB

#create new connectionstring with elements modified
$Newconnectionstring=($Hash.Keys | %{"$_=$($Hash[$_])"}) -join ";"

$Newconnectionstring
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This definitely helps me get the variables in place for what i'm trying to do. The next thing i'm looking into is how to specify what text to actually grab and replace using this information. I could call out Server= and Database=, but  the amount of characters in the server or database name will vary. Is there a way to have it grab a string between the = and ;?  For example, if this was the string i was replacing localSQLConString=Database=Demodatabase;Server=DemoServer\SQLEXPRESS14;Integrated Security=True;